# trouble plotting shapefiles in R with geom_sf

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, shapefile

I'm trying to plot shapefiles in R using `ggplot2` and `sf` to call `geom_sf` but it's throwing errors that I can't seem to work around. I am able to plot the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame without issue using `plot()` but I'd like to work with `ggplot` and `geom_sf` if possible.

The shapefiles can be found here: https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Neighborhoods/bbvz-uum9

Here's what should be a MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rgdal)

nbrhd_shp <- readOGR(dsn = shapefile_filepath, layer = "geo_export_00bf6ede-a61b-4746-8c69-e1510a184344")
class(nbrhd_shp)

plot(nbrhd_shp)
```

these both work. The `class(nbrhd_shp)` returns as expected:

```
> class(nbrhd_shp)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

But when I try to plot with `ggplot` I get a blank plot with coordinate labels on the axes and an error message:

```
ggplot(nbrhd_shp) +
  geom_sf(data = nbrhd_shp@data, aes(geometry = nbrhd_shp@polygons))+
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(nbrhd_shp))

Regions defined for each Polygons
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_sf()`
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'st_bbox' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should convert it to an sf object first.

```
nbrhd_shp <- st_as_sf(nbrhd_shp)
ggplot(nbrhd_shp) + geom_sf()
```

[image]